# New to OOP - using List(of T) or Collection()

Tags: vb.net

I'm not positive that I'm using `Lists` correctly. I'm VERY new to OOP and a lot of the documentation on MSDN assumes I understand lingo that I don't always.

I created the classes (`ItemData` and `Materials`) as part of a new item creation application. Both classes have many other properties in them, but they've been simplified for this example.

```
Public Class ItemData
    Public FamilyID As String
    Public Description As String
    'Public Material As New Collection() -- using collection didnt give me access to the properties in the Material class.
    Public Material as new List(of Material) 
   ... (Other Properties)
End Class

Public Class Material
    Public _MaterialID As String
    Property MaterialID() As String
        Get
           Return _MaterialID
       End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MaterialID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ... (Other Properties)
EndClass
```

Items are grouped using a FamilyID in the ItemData class and each packaging variation is a new Material containing its own set of properties.

Goal:

```
NewItem.FamilyID = "ITEM0001"
NewItem.Material(1).MaterialID = "ITEM000101"
NewItem.Material(1).UnitofMeasure = "CASE"
NewItem.Material(2).MaterialID = "ITEM000102"
NewItem.Material(2).UnitofMeasure = "BOX"
```

In the application I have created an instance of ItemData and I can assign values to the properties directly within the ItemData class,  but I cannot figure out how to add a new Material.

```
Public Class CreateNewItem
    Public NewItem As New ItemData
    Private Sub AssignMaterialID(FamilyID As String)
        Dim MaterialCount As Long = NewItem.Material.LongCount

        NewItem.Material.Add(MaterialCount + 1)
        NewItem.Material(MaterialCount + 1).MaterialID = "ITEM000101"
        NewItem.Material(MaterialCount + 1).UnitofMeasure= "CASE"        
    End Sub
EndClass
```

Comment: There are a thousand things that could be said about this. A few: 1) this: `Public FamilyID As String` is not a property, is a Field. You may want to transform it in a readonly Auto-Property: `Public ReadOnly Property FamilyID As String`, so it can only be set in the class constructor. Probably the same for the `Description` Field.  2) This: `Public _MaterialID As String` is a backing Field, used by the `MaterialID` property. It must be declared `Private` (not accessible from outside the class). The code generator should have done that for you, when you entered `prop` + `TAB`.

Comment: 3) When you want to add a new Material object to the list of materials of the `ItemData` class, you need to add a new `Material` object, not a *number*: it's a `List(Of Material)`, not a `List(Of Long)`. Create a new Material: `Dim itemMaterial as new Material() with { .MaterialID = "[Some ID]", .UnitofMeasure= "CASE"  (...)}`. Then add it: `NewItem.Materials.Add(itemMaterial)` 4) `UnitofMeasure` should be an `Enumerator` (...)

Comment: thank you. I have adjusted my Public_properties to Private _properties because the rationale makes sense; I still need to think about the other part re: class constructor (google terms for tomorrow).

Comment: **Nope**. The properties must be `Public`, setting them `Private` defeats the purpose of having properties in this case. `ReadOnly` and `Private`, two different things. The class constructor is simply `Public Sub New()`. You could have a constructor like this: `Public Sub New(ID As String, Description As String)`, so you can only build a new class if you already have an ID and a Description to assign to the new object. In the construtor you then set the `FamilyID` and `Description` properties. Since they're ReadOnly, they can only be set in the class constructor.

Comment: I would choose a different name for your List(Of Material) in your ItemData class. Perhaps Materials as the plural would indicate a collection of some kind.

Comment: thank you again. this is working as expected. Part of the hangup for me was that I dont have all the values of the properties at the time i create Material and even using your method (until I stepped through the result) I couldnt see where an index was assigned to refer to later when I wanted to fill those details in. I'm good now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option in my opinion would be to define constructor accepting arguments to populate fields in `Material` class and then easily create objects and add them to list, like below:

```
Imports System

Module Program
  Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim newItem As New ItemData
    newItem.Material.Add(New Material("ITEM000101", "CASE"))
    ' etc.
  End Sub
End Module

Public Class ItemData
  Public FamilyID As String
  Public Description As String
  Public Material As New List(Of Material)
End Class

Public Class Material
  ' All your code can be simplified
  Public Property MaterialID As String
  Public Property UnitofMeasure As String

  Public Sub New(MaterialID As String, UnitofMeasure As String)
    Me.MaterialID = MaterialID
    Me.UnitofMeasure = UnitofMeasure
  End Sub
End Class
```

Also, you need to make your properties `Public` in order to access them from "the outside". You should read a bit about access modifiers.

Comment: Thank you. I did simplify the Materials class. I'm not sure why I thought it needed the whole get and set thing (this is my newness to OOP showing). As for the constructor, there are lots and lots of attributes - not just the two i listed - and the attributes are added at various times through the item creation process, some of them are optional etc. I have a working solution, however using all the help I've received here. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @Mavryk76 You are welcome. You should mark answer, you think helped you the most, as accepted (green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of the material class and set it, like this.

```
    NewItem.Material.Add(New Material With {.MaterialID = "ITEM000101", .UnitofMeasure = "CASE"})
    NewItem.Material.Add(New Material With {.MaterialID = "ITEM000102", .UnitofMeasure = "BOX"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello try Array instead of collections, 
besides It seems you forgot the Type for the variable

Dim Material() As String

Hope works well ...

Comment: I don't think array lets me assign properties, which means my program would need to keep track of which element is filled or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: When you create an array of a type (any type) you can always use any property of that class.  you can use array of "ItemData" so every item on the array has its on collection of materials then you can do whatever you want.